# Ideas when solving $N(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible when giving a basis for the subspace $N(A^T)$ that $N(A^T) $ = zero vector?

*Note: N(A^T) is the left nullspace

For example, if

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 &-1& 0 \\ 2 & 4 & -1 & -1  \\ \end{bmatrix}$
and

$A^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2\\ 2 & 4 \\ -1 & -1\\ 0&-1  \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Then reduced row echelon form is...

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2\\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0& 0  \\ \end{bmatrix}$

so would  $x_1=-2x_2$
so N(A^T): (-2,1)

or is $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$ so N(A^T): {0}?

I guess what's tripping me up is that fact that each variable is a pivot, so I feel like $N(A^T): (-2,1)$, but part of me thinks is should be$ N(A^T): {0}$. Which one is right? Can someone explain?

Comment: The matrix you write is the **row echelon form** which is **NOT** the same thing as the **reduced** *row echelon form*.  It has not yet been reduced.

Comment: A rather quick answer as well would come in the form of the *rank-nullity theorem* which says $rank(A)+nullity(A)=n$  (*nullity is the dimension of the nullspace*).  You see that the rank of $A^T$ is $2$ and there are two columns, so $nullity(A)+rank(A)=nullity(A)+2=2$ so $nullity(A)=\dots$ implying...

Answer (score 0):

From $\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2\\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0& 0  \\ \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0\\  0  \\ \end{bmatrix}$ you get

$x_1+2x_2=0$ and $x_2=0$, hence $x_1=x_2=0$